# Finding a smaller dataset with a similar covariance matrix

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I'm interested in solving the following problem:

> Given a dataset $\mathcal{X} = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^p$, find a smaller set $\mathcal{Y} = \{y_i\}_{i=1}^k\subset{\mathbb{R}^p}$ whose sample covariance matrix, $C_\mathcal{Y}$, is a good approximation to that of $\mathcal{X}$, $C_{\mathcal{X}}$.

To make this a little more precise, is there a good way of finding $\mathcal{Y}$ such that $\left\|C_\mathcal{X} - \mathcal{C}_\mathcal{Y}\right\| \le \varepsilon$, or such that $\left\|C_{\mathcal{X}} - C_{\mathcal{Y}}\right\|$ is near-minimal for fixed $k$?

One idea would be to choose $\mathcal{Y}$ by sampling $\mathcal{X}$ at random. Perhaps a better way to do this, though, is to make $\mathcal{Y}$ the result of [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd's_algorithm)/$k$-means on $\mathcal{X}$, which would help to better summarize the entire dataset.

In general, is there a decent way to solve this problem, preferably with good theoretical bounds on $\left\|C_{\mathcal{X}} - C_{\mathcal{Y}}\right\|$ (where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is just a common matrix norm, e.g. Frobenius or spectral)?

Ideally I could find $\mathcal{Y}$ in time complexity similar to that of Lloyd's algorithm, or at least in time that is sub-quadratic in $n$ (so preferably cheaper than doing something like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)). But if you have ideas for methods/algorithms that are more computationally expensive that haven't been mentioned here I'd also appreciate hearing those.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really care only about the covariance and not about other aspects of the empirical distribution as well? What about the mean or the skew of the sample for example?

Comment: And how would you use PCA to achieve this? Wouldn't PCA be used to reduce the dimension, i.e. going from $p$ to a smaller $q$?

Comment: I'm interested in finding $\mathcal{Y}$ for which PCA gets roughly the same results as doing PCA on the original set $\mathcal{X}$, so I only care about the covariance matrix. To do it with PCA, if you do a SVD you get $C_{\mathcal{X}} = W\Sigma^{\top}\Sigma W^{\top}$. Let $\mathcal{Y} = c\begin{bmatrix}W\hat{\Sigma}^{\top} & -W\hat{\Sigma}^{\top}\end{bmatrix}^{\top}$ (with $\hat{\Sigma}$ containing the top $k$ singular values, $c$ a scaling factor)... with appropriate $c$ I believe $C_{\mathcal{Y}} = W\hat{\Sigma}^{\top}\hat{\Sigma}W^{\top}$ which is a good approximation to $C_{\mathcal{X}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which produces a sample $\mathcal{Y}$ such that $C_\mathcal{Y} = C_\mathcal{X}$.

Let $y_{ij}$ be the $j$ coordinate of event $i$, where $i=1,2,...,k$ and $j=1,2,...,p$. Require $k$ to be even.

Choose $k=2m$ to be large enough, so that $m$ events have at least the same number of degrees of freedom as $C_\mathcal{X}$. In other words
$$ m\,p \ge \frac{1}{2}\,p\,(p+1) \ \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \ m \ge \frac{1}{2}\,(p+1)$$

The sample consists of pairs of events, $\vec{y}_{i+m} = - \vec{y}_i$ to ensure that the sample mean is $0$, to simplify calculations.

Solve the set of quadratic equations for the event coordinates:

$$\eqalign{
{C_\mathcal{X}}_{jj}=\frac{2}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k/2}y_{ij}^2 \\
{C_\mathcal{X}}_{jj'}=\frac{2}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k/2}y_{ij}y_{ij'}
}
$$